# Magento Product Custom Ordering

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento based website (http://www.apoyowellness.com/index.php/).

Here you can see a best seller section , I have added a custom field "Featured" from which the products are tagged to featured that are shown in best sellers.

My problem is that I want to re-arrange the products as per the sort weight custom field I have defined in the product catalog.

I have attached a custom field sort_order to the product catalog and every product has its sort weight/number like 1,2,3,4 etc. I want to show the product according to the numbering in ascending order.

I have a for each loop which gives me all the attributes of products just want a help how can a loop all the products inside for each in ascending order of given numbers (1,2,3 etc). Below is my for each code:

```
             <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): //print_r($_product); ?>

         <?php if($_product->featured == 1): ?>


             <div class="reco-sgl">

              <div class="product-image-wrapper borderlnright">
               <div class="single-products">
                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                 <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                  <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(); ?>"  alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                 </a>   
                 <p><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></p>
                 <?php echo $this->getFeaturedProductHtml() ?>

                 <h4><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?></h4>
                 <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a> </div>
               </div>
              </div>

             </div>


            <?php endif; ?>
         <?php endforeach ?>
```

Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create 2 product attributes one is YES/NO type.

1. "featured_product" for Featured products
2. "sort_order" for custom sorting number like 1,2,3,4 etc

   ```
   $limitnumber = 10;

   $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('featured_product', array('eq' => '1'))->addAttributeToSort('sort_order', 'asc');

   Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
   // version magento CM 1.9.0.1
   //Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($products);
   $products->setPageSize($limitnumber)->setCurPage(1)->load();
   foreach ($products->getItems() as $product){
       echo $product->getName();
       // your code
   }
   ```

Comment: can you please elaborate more .. did i need to copy your entire code to my file ??

Comment: you can create a separate block or can write into phtml file directly.

Comment: Thanks you I have written in directly into the phtml file with little modification in your code .. thanks you so much :) @suman singh

Answer (score 0):

Before loop add `$_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('sort_order', 'ASC');`. Remember that attribute must selected as 'Used in Product Listing' and 'Used for Sorting in Product Listing' in admin dashboard(Manage Attributes).

Comment: Not working bro :( I have added this see below :-

I have Selected USed Product and Sorting also but still not working here is the below code :-


{<?php $_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('sort_order', 'ASC');
    
    foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): //print_r($_product); ?>

Comment: No , Did i need to reindex ?? I am intermediate  to magento where to reindex

Comment: `System > Index Management`and check if update is required.